# How can I start an Electron 7.x.x main.js with package.json in parent directory?

Tags: node.js, electron, package.json

I have an application that essentially is a website that can optionally be opened with electron.

```
root
|-package.json
|-src
| |-(source code)
|-electron
  |-main.electron.js
```

It was built with Electron 2.x.x and worked well. Now I decided to update to Electron 7.x.x it seems that I am forced to have `main.electron.js` in the same directory as package.json or to create a second package.json for electron specifics. If not, running electron breaks with an error that no package.json was found in the /electron directory.

For reasons not important, I want to keep my old structure and not have to add a package.json, move main.electron.js or add a main.js that points to main.electron.js.

Is there anything I can add to package.json or maybe main.electron.js to get it to use the package.json of the parent directory?

Note: In electron's documentation they generally use the two package.json style but allude to only using one package.json file, I just can't find anything on how to accomplish it with the newest version of electron.

Comment: Please include what your package.json looks like in your answer

Comment: Why do you need the specific package.json? The question here is not project specific. My example above is a hypothetical. Suppose you want to put electron 7.x.x starting point in a child directory of a larger app and don’t want to add an additional package.json in its directory, how do you get electron to use the package.json in the root directory? This is assuming that everything in package.json is set correctly except linking electron to it.

Comment: If I understand what you're asking for correctly, couldn't this be achieved by having the "script" key in your package.json contain: "start": "electron ./electron/main.electron.js"

Comment: You would think so. That’s essentially what I am doing and what used to work. Now it rejects it because package.json is not in the same directory as main.electron.js

Comment: I just tested this with version 7.1.4 using the guide https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/first-app#running-your-app The only thing I replaced in the guide was the "start" key in the "script" section and it seemed to work fine for the structure you specified.

Comment: I've created this gist https://gist.github.com/dibenso/6259f2dad4d938870329e6e927698a6b to show exactly what's going on

Comment: Did you move the entry file to a sub directory, so that electron and package.json are not in the same directory?

Comment: Interesting, the only difference is that I use electron 7.1.3. Hmm

Comment: main.electron.js is still in the electron directory

Comment: I also switched to 7.1.3 and is still working fine

Comment: Thanks for all the help Dillon. I found the source. I’m using electron-reload to hot load in dev mode. For some reason it’s taking issue with package.json. Ones I removed it, everything worked again. Now I guess I’ll try to find out what the problem with electron-reload is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyone stopping by here who has the same problem. It might be electron-reload causing the problem. Try commenting it out and run again. The comments above explains the process of coming to this conclusion.

ANSWER:
Remove the following line from your main.electron.js file

`require('electron-reload')(__dirname);`

There may be other modules that could cause the same problem. This was what solved it for me.